# Unable to suppress WARN message in JUnit Test

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have a JUnit4 test executed with Maven which emits the following WARN Message:

```
WARN: RESTEASY002145: NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load builtin provider org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DataSourceProvider from jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-core/4.7.2.Final/resteasy-core-4.7.2.Final.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
```

Until I find a proper fix for this WARN, I'd like to suppress this message. I have tried varios combinations, such as:

```
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("RESTEASY002145")
```

or

```
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError")
```

but none worked for me. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: SuppressWarnings is to suppress warnings during compilations.  In your case, you want them to be removed from your log file if I understand correctly.   RESTEasy is what is displaying these messages, so not Junit.  You will need to set your logging lib to log org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers package to INFO instead.  This will remove all WARN messages for this org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers package

Comment: Thanks. I see. I thought the @SuppressWarnings were able to suppress also on the warnings generated by test execution. Seems I've misunderstood it. Thanks